# Is there a way to control an email service like yahoo using javascript?

Tags: javascript, email, browser-addons

I am making an open-source addon for firefox and chrome called  and I am wondering if there is a way to control an email service like yahoo using javascript?

Comment: It there a way, YES. At least the emails, not the service itself. Go take a look at how Thunderbird works.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the look of the page and probably (although I cannot be sure) send and edit messages without having to use the on-page buttons, but you cannot do server-side stuff such as logging into an account from a page without a log-in on it or sending a message from a page other than the email sending page. If you have any specific questions about controlling one specific thing, please add them in the comments, and I may answer them.